# Angular Material DatePicker not converting date in UTC format

Tags: angular, angular-material, datetimepicker, utc

I have this date `1589673600000` which is `Sun May 17 2020 00:00:00` in `UTC` and `Sat May 16 2020 20:00:00` in `local timezone`. I am using moment.js along with Angular Material DatePicker in my Angualr webapp.

```
console.log(moment.utc(this.leiData.renewalDate).toISOString());

this.renewalDate = new FormControl(moment.utc(this.leiData.renewalDate).toISOString(), [Validators.required])
```

The `console.log` prints **2020-05-17T00:00:00.000Z** on the console but the datepicker on the UI displays `5/16/2020` i.e. in local timezone format.

I am using `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS` with `useUtc` flag set to true.

**app.module.ts**

```
 providers: [
        DatePipe,
        { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } },
      ],
```

Comment: im facing same issue, have you found solution ?

Comment: I used moment's utc method 
moment.utc(this.leiData.renewalDate)